System.IndexOutOfRangeException: "Индекс находился вне границ массива."
Я новенький в С# и не понимаю почему ошибка .
В файле маp находится что то типо того :
######################
#   #    #           #
##                   #
####                 #
#################    #
######################

КОД:
        private static char[,] ReadMap(string path) 
        { 
            string[] Fille = File.ReadAllLines("map.txt");
            char[,]map = new char[LongestArrayElement(Fille), Fille.Length];


            for (int x = 0;x < map.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < map.GetLength(1); y++) 
                {
                    map[x, y] = Fille[y][x];
                }
            }
            return map;
        }


А вы проверяли размерность map?

Само название LongestArrayElement намекает на разность длин строк в файле. Будь они одинаковые, то самую длинную бы искать не нужно было

IndexOutOfRangeException означает попытку обратиться к элементу по индексу, который находится за границами массива. Например, у вас массив из трёх элементов arr = [1, 2, 3]. третий элемент можно получить по индексу arr[2] (в C# элементы индексируются начиная с 0). Если попытаться обратиться к arr[3], то это уже будет 4-ый элемент, которого нет в массиве, что вызовет IndexOutOfRangeException исключение

Проблема, судя по всему, в LongestArrayElement(Fille). Какого результата Вы хотите добиться? Повернуть массив или отзеркалить его?
